# Expand a numpy array based on a value in another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array `a = np.array([1,1,2,1,3])` that should be transformed into the following array `b = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])`.

What happens is that all the **non 1 values** in the `a` array should be expanded in the `b` array to their multiple defined in the `a` array. Simpler said, the `2` should become **2 ones**, and the `3` should become **3 ones**.

Frankly, I couldn't find a numpy function that does this, but I'm sure one exists. Any advice would be very welcome! Thank you!

Comment: look at np.repeat

Comment: @Divakar, oh my god ... My mind must have been on holiday. Thank you, more than happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply do -

```
np.ones(a.sum(),dtype=int)
```

This will accomodate all numbers : `1s` and non-`1s`, because of the summing and hence give us the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [71]: np.ones(len(a),int).repeat(a)                                          
Out[71]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

For this small example it is faster than `np.ones(a.sum(),int)`, but it doesn't scale quite as well.  But overall both are fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way based on the number you wanna be repeated:

```
In [12]: a = np.array([1,1,2,1,3])
In [13]: mask = a != 1
In [14]: np.concatenate((a[~mask], np.repeat(1, np.prod(a[mask]))))
Out[14]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```